# How to add images to button with mouse over and mouse out?

Tags: java, html, css, user-interface, primefaces

I have one button and i want to add a onmouseover and onmouseout effect to that button.
I have two images for both onmouseover and onmouseout effects
I have tried this

```
<p:commandButton onmouseover="../images/add_on_18.png" 
                 onmouseout="../images/add_off_18.png" 
                 value="New" />
```

Can you help me?

## **UpDate**

I have tried this. No use. 
Still not getting the proper UI

XHtml Code:

```
 <p:commandButton value="New" 
                  styleClass = "btnBckg" 
                  actionListener="#{routeController.createNewRoute}" 
                  update=":routeHeaderForm"/>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .btnBckg {
        background-image: url('../images/add_off_18.png');
    }

    .btnBckg:hover {
        background-image: url('../images/add_on_18.png');
    }
```

Comment: don't you prefer to just change its appearance on hover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,... what about CSS ? Add `styleClass` to your `p:commandButton` and style it with CSS in external stylesheet like this :

Facelet code:

```
  <p:commandButton value="New"
                     styleClass = "btnBckg" 
                     actionListener="#{routeController.createNewRoute}" 
                     update=":routeHeaderForm"/>
```

CSS code:

```
    .btnBckg {
        background-image: url('../resources/images/image1.png');
    }

    .btnBckg:hover {
        background-image: url('../resources/images/image2.png');
    }
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: @user1874744 Well I've tried it just now and it is working for me. Does it work and it is not what you want or it is not working at all for you ?

Comment: it's not working at all. I'm using prime faces. don't know how to implement for prime faces.

Comment: Ok and have you imported the created **CSS file** in your **.xhtml** ? If you did, try to replace `background-image:...` for `background: red` in `.btnBckg` and for `background: blue` in `.btnBckg:hover`. If it is working (switching colors) then your image **paths** are not correctly specified.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="../images/image1.png" 
     onmouseover="this.src='../images/image2.png'" 
     onmouseout="this.src='../images/image1.png'" />
```

Hope this helps.. :)